# Access Xcode and emulator features from a remote mac mini for IOS App Development

Tags: ios, xcode, windows, macos, virtual-machine

I have a requirement for Mobile App development for both Android and IOS. Android development has done smoothly with Native Code. But for IOS development we don't have a Mac Machine to use. Only option the client has provided is a Mac Mini which shall be shared remotely . We have Windows machines to access the Mac remotely.

After searching through the net found some alternatives like macincloud , xcodeclub etc. but not needed as the client is already allowing us to access their mac machine.

Would like to know whether it hampers the development in any ways such as emulator, testing, or even use of Titanium or similar tools if required. Some of the advises were mainly pointing out the slowness of this approach as well as the Connecting windows machine configurations should match to specific mini mac config. Bit confused to work a way out.

Please advise.

Comment: Why not create a virtual machine with `OS X`? Your other choice would be connect to the clients machine using `VNC`, but that might be quite slow and cludgy as you mentioned.

Comment: IMHO if you're serious you can't finish development using simulators only. At some point you would have to connect physical devices to the Mac mini (or whatever). So I wouldn't go down the road of relying on the remote Mac (alone).

Comment: @l'L'l . Thanks for the response. So creating a virtual machine will be much better than connecting remotely to the client's machine?

Comment: @Drux . Thanks . I was thinking on a later stage i shall be asking the client to connect an actual device for us like a UAT. Can that be too risky?

Comment: Even if you have a super fast connection to the clients machine you'll probably find using XCode remotely then running the iOS emulator too clunky and laggy at times; you never know until you try I guess :)

Comment: @user2695433 Unless this is a very tiny project it's not a good path IMO. (What is your budget range, if one may ask?)

Comment: @l'L'l  yes i too fear that. Doesn't the virtual machine require licensed copy of OSX to be installed as vdmk file? or can share the client's keys?

Comment: Unlike Windows there are no installation keys required for OS X. It is, however, a breach of the license conditions to install it on non-Apple hardware.